# Using :active for CSS coding for labels in Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

I've been trying to code my label list in the right hand sidebar of my blog (http://www.themaidenover.blogspot.com) and I have found that I cannot edit the label once it has been selected.

I've tried to use the :active code in the CSS but I am relatively inexperienced in this area and I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

```
.Label a {
    padding-left:0px;
    background:#ffffff no-repeat scroll 5px 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 20px;
    color:#333333!important;
    border-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font: 14px Georgia, verdana;
    color:#333333;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0px;
}
.Label a:hover {
    border:1px solid #555555;
    text-decoration:none;
    ccolor:#555555
}
.Label a:active {
    padding-left:0px;
    background:#ffffff no-repeat scroll 5px 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 20px;
    color:#333333!important;
    border-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font: 14px Georgia, verdana;
    color:#333333;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0px;
}
```

Help is much appreciated, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have problem when you click on link. If you see in inspect element you will find that there is no link when you go to page so first solve that problem if it is not an issue then use this css hope this will work

```
.Label .label-size span
   { 
   padding-left:0px; 
   background:#ffffff no-repeat scroll 5px 10px;
   list-style-type: none; 
   padding:5px 5px 5px 20px; 
   color:#333333!important; 
   border-radius:7px; 
  -moz-border-radius:7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;  
   text-decoration:none;font: 14px Georgia, verdana; color:#333333; 
   border: 1px solid #dddddd;
   float:left; 
   margin: 0 0 5px 0px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add below css class

```
.Label span{
    background: none no-repeat scroll 5px 10px #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: #333333 !important;
    float: left;
    font: 14px Georgia,verdana;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```